# Xcode crashes when selecting "Show commit" from context menu

Tags: ios, xcode, git

After I upgraded to Xcode 15 it keep crashing if I select this option of "Show commit".
This menu can be opened by selecting "Show last change for line" -> "Show commit". Before with Xcode 14 it was working well.
[image: crashing while selecting this option]

Expected Result:
Xcode should open commit in history editor